# iCloud: Bind the ID I assign to user in my app to user's Apple ID

Tags: objective-c, icloud

Hello and sorry for the confusing title of my question.

My app assigns a numeric ID to every user that install it on his iDevice, allowing him to use it (it's a social photo sharing app) without entering personal data or other annoying detail. Every photo is uploaded on a web server and bound to the internal user ID, and can be retrieved without entering any password. The problem is when a user uninstalls and reinstalls the app, or he wants to use it on two different iDevices (e.g. iPhone and iPad) that share the same apple ID.

This seems to be a job for iCloud. What I'm asking to myself is, in my case, I have only to store a key->value on iCloud with the user ID my app has generated. Is it a secure way to identify a user by his apple ID, or it will be vulnerable to identity theft?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: the whole architecture you describe is insecure and vulnerbale... not only to identity theft...

Comment: Hi Yahia, thank you for your comment. Could you be more descriptive about the vulnerabilities you mention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect the iCloud Key Value store to be fairly secure, although maybe not as secure as using the keychain on the device.  In fact, you may want to use the keychain since that's more persistent than the iCloud key-value store.

If a user has one device, then runs your app which stores an ID in iCloud, then deletes your app, the iCloud key-value store for your app will be deleted as well. So if they reinstall the app you won't find a previous ID stored in iCloud.  However, the keychain is more persistent so that might be a better place to store a User ID. (I understand this doesn't help you sync an account across a user's different devices so maybe you'll have to use a combination of the keychain, iCloud and your server to accomplish this).

Check out this brief post on [storing a unique ID in the keychain](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/08/21/dev-juice-help-me-generate-unique-identifiers/). It talks about how the keychain won't survive a complete reinstall that isn't a restore from backup.